# Xcode downloading normal?

Tags: xcode, ios5

I recently installed Xcode 4.3.1 from the App Store.  It constantly says "Downloading iOS 5.1 SDK." Isn't that already on my computer with the download? Every time I close and reopen the app, it seems the downloads restart.  Is this normal?

Comment: Popover segues are for iPad storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably downloading the documentation. You can control this in the preferences--> downloads settings.

It should finish eventually, the documentation is pretty huge.